# Cardano-node hello world

Tags: cardano

I went through the installation instructions here:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-sl/blob/develop/docs/how-to/build-cardano-sl-and-daedalus-from-source-code.md

When I finally finish installing stack and nix, and get to this point:

```
$ nix-build -A cardano-sl-node-static --out-link master
$ ls master/bin
cardano-node-simple
```

I see the build was successful.  I try to run the node:

So when I run:

```
./master/bin/cardano-node-simple  --system-start 1495462345
```

per flags I see [here](https://cardanodocs.com/technical/cli-options/), I get:

```
[diffusion:ERROR:ThreadId 25] [2018-10-25 02:30:51.99 UTC] DNS resolution for [NodeAddrDNS "todo.defaultDnsDomain.com" Nothing] gave no results
[diffusion:ERROR:ThreadId 25] [2018-10-25 02:30:51.99 UTC] DNS resolution failure for [NodeAddrDNS "todo.defaultDnsDomain.com" Nothing]: [NameError]
[diffusion:ERROR:ThreadId 25] [2018-10-25 02:30:51.99 UTC] DNS resolution for [NodeAddrDNS "todo.defaultDnsDomain.com" Nothing] gave no results
[diffusion:ERROR:ThreadId 25] [2018-10-25 02:30:51.99 UTC] DNS resolution failure for [NodeAddrDNS "todo.defaultDnsDomain.com" Nothing]: [NameError]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Doesn't the error message, that he can't get a name resolution for `todo.defaultDnsDomain.com` suggest, that this might be a configuration error and probably has nothing to do with nix?

Comment: I would like to believe so, but left in because there were by my count 22 different build targets in the instructions, and I would not be surprised if someone from the project answers this with "oh, here are different nix-build flags you need to get DNS resolution settings to accept defaults."

Comment: We really need a Cardano-specific Stack Exchange website

Comment: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125174/cardano